# How to include a filed to while loop query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used `foreach` in my query for retrieving data but in here in the middle of the page I have a field `$row['RemoteEmployeeID']` which is out of while loop and I am unable to include it to while loop, if I include it so my header is going to be repeated with each and every record.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
<?php
error_reporting('0');
  ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL= ../../spd/myaccount.php">';
  exit();
}
else 
{
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');

$query = "SELECT 
   properties.PropertyID,
   properties.PropertyType,
   properties.PropertyDealType,
   properties.Status,
   properties.PropostedPrice,
   properties.PropertyStatus,
   properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail,
   properties.PropertyDealerName,
   properties.PropertyOwnerName,
   remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID

   FROM  remoteemployees, properties

    WHERE remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeEmail = properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail   

   AND  properties.RemoteEmployeeEmail = '".$email."'

   AND  properties.Status= 'Active'

   AND  properties.PropertyStatus= 'APPROVED'


   ORDER BY properties.PropertyID
   ";


  $query_run = $connection->query($query);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($res=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) {
                $count      =   $query_run->num_rows;          // Taking the number of queries returened by the result
                $array[]    =   $res;
  }
         ?>
<div style="float:left;"><font color="#000000">Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> 
</font>
</div>
<div style="float:right; color:#999; width:600px; margin-left:155px;">


<a href="#" class="button">My Contract Copy</a>

<a href="#" class="button">My Property List</a>

<a href="#" class="button">My Trans.History</a>

<a href="Remote Employee profile.php?RemoteEmployeeid=<?php echo $row['RemoteEmployeeID'] ?>" class="button" >My Profile</a>

<a href="logout.php" class="button">Logout</a>


</div>


</div>

<div class="Labelcon">
  <div class="Label">Property ID</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Type</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Deal Type</div>
  <div class="Labelowner">Property Owner</div>
  <div class="Labeldealer">Property Dealer</div>
  <div class="Label">Proposted Price</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Status</div>
</div>
<?php
        // Here is the start of the loop
        foreach($array as $row) { ?>

<div class="Valuecon">
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyID'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyType'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealType']?></div>
  <div class="Valueowner"><?php echo $row['PropertyOwnerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Valuedealer"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropostedPrice'];?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyStatus'];?></div>
</div>

<?php 

  if($query_run->num_rows == 0)
  {
      echo 'No Records Found';
  }

}}
?>
</div>
<p></p>
<center>
<?php $queryemail= "SELECT SUM(transactions.EarnAmount) AS TotalEarn, transactions.TaxDeduction,

SUM(transactions.AmountPaid) AS TotalPaid from transactions WHERE transactions.RemoteEmployeeID = ".$row['RemoteEmployeeID']." limit 1"; ?>
<div class="Amountpayablepaid">

  <div class="amountpayable">

      <div class="aclabel">Earn Amount:</div>

      <div class="acvalue">

      <?php
       $queryemail_run = $connection->query($queryemail);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$queryemail_run->fetch_assoc()) 
  {   
      ?>
      <div class="USD">
      <?php echo 'USD '.$row['TotalEarn'];  ?>
      </div>


      </div>
      <br>
    <br>  
  </div>
  <div class="amountpaid">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Tax Deduction:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo $row['TaxDeduction'].' %'; ?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

  <div class="amountpaid" style="margin-top:22px;">

      <div class="acpaidlable">Amount Paid:</div>

      <div class="acpaidvalue">

        <div class="USDpaid"><?php echo 'USD '.$row['TotalPaid'];}?></div>


      </div>

  </div>

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I honestly think you are showing too much code. You should only show what is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Simple:

```
$RemoteEmp = null;
$count = $query_run->num_rows;

while($res=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[]    =   $res;
    $RemoteEmp = $res["RemoteEmployeeID"];
```

}

Now :

```
<a href="Remote Employee profile.php?RemoteEmployeeid=<?php echo $RemoteEmp; ?>" class="button" >My Profile</a>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked when I need for others of my menus so i should change only the RemoteEmployeeID in array

Comment: @Priyabapat, `mysql_` is deprecated as in PHP 5.5.0, So If your version of PHP gona change in future, then your entire script stoped running. Be a Smart Programmer and start using `mysqli_ or PDO` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Is there any way to converted automatically or not ?

Comment: No there is not way, You have to change your scripts manually. But yes Best Option is Use PDO, it will give you to indepandency to move on PHP supported Database in single line.

Comment: What do you mean by indepandency to move on PHP supported Database in single line

Comment: I mean, Like in future you want to move from `mysql` database to `oracle`